# Detect Settings Charm is Opened or Not in Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, appsettings

I just want to know is that Any other way to get the Settings Charm is active or not.
Because, In my app, the Settings of an app is in the settings charm(If user presses Settings btn in App will leads to open Settings Charm)

In my case, Instead of using the settings btn. user may use short cut (WIN + C) (or) Moving the Mouse to the Right corner of the Screen. to enter into the settings pane means how could i know that?

Is that any way to find that????

Comment: What is your actual problem? Do you want to pause your game when this happens? Just check for loss of activation. That will cover Charms, Settings, Switch, and other cases where the user has stopped using your app temporarily. Or do you want to detect when the user has requested your app to display its settings? Use the Settings contract.

Answer (score 0):

Tap in to [CommandsRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.applicationsettings.settingspane.commandsrequested.aspx) on the [SettingsPane](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br241896.aspx)

```
Occurs when the user opens the settings pane. Listening for this event lets the app 
initialize the setting commands and pause its UI until the user closes the pane.
```

Now detecting that it's closed again would amount to checking that your window is again activated - [see this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/a3118b41-50a3-40af-b010-bc7b9e99d4c4).